# Set "display_name" property on account creation

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

When I create an Account, how can I set the "display_name" property?

I have checked through the docs (https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_account), and in their example response the display_name is set to "Stripe.com".

Currently, in my application, it is set to "MyProject.com".

Answer (score 1):

You're unable to set display_name via the Api. Its only used in Stripe's dashboard for setting what appears in the top right of the Dashboard. It is settable as the `Account Name` in the account settings.